# How to connect to a private cluster in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, vpc

I am trying to move data from MySQL databases over to Amazon Redshift as securely as possible.  I have been able to connect to the cluster, using boto3 to put a csv into S3, create a table in redshift for the data, then use the copy command to move the data from S3 to redshift.  This was all while having the cluster set to publicly accessible.

I realized for our security needs, it is probably best to have the cluster set to private.  However, after doing this, I was no longer able to connect to redshift to create tables, load data from S3, and the SQL clients I had been using to query with would no longer connect.  However, my VPC is set to allow my IP to connect.  Does anyone know how to connect to a private cluster?

*sidenote, this is all still in a research and development phase so we have not actually put any sensitive data in the cloud

Answer (score 2):

From [Creating a Cluster in a VPC - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/getting-started-cluster-in-vpc.html):

> **Publicly Accessible:** Select *Yes* if you want the cluster to have a public IP address that can be accessed from the public internet, select *No* if you want the cluster to have a private IP addressed that can only be accessed from within the VPC.

By selecting *No*, the cluster no longer has a public IP address. This means it **can only be accessed from within the VPC**. You do not state from where you are connecting to Redshift, but it sounds like you are doing it from the Internet.

A common way that people connect to a private database (that is not accessible from the Internet) is to use **port forwarding** through a Bastion Server (or "Jump Box") that is accessible from the Internet.

For an example, see: [Easy ssh tunneling and port forwarding | AVM Consulting](https://www.avmconsulting.net/single-post/2017/11/23/Easy-ssh-tunneling-and-port-forwarding)

The **Security Group** associated with the Redshift instance also needs to permit access from where ever you are connecting.

Comment: Thank you, I have been researching using an EC2 instance as a bastion server to connect

Answer (score 0):

> I realized for our security needs, it is probably best to have the cluster set to private.

Everything in AWS, could be public/private/custom security enabled, its good you have enabled VPC now and made it private.

> However, after doing this, I was no longer able to connect to Redshift to create tables, load data from S3, and the SQL clients I had been using to query with would no longer connect.

You could connect using any client thick(psql) vs thin(jdbc/odbc) to Redshift with your proper credentials and URL. Example psql:

```
psql postgresql://username:password@redhift-url-datawarehouse.:5439/dbname?sslmode=require
```

S3 you make it private or private files and then use copy function by supplying your IAM role and credentials while doing `Copy`.

Here is example copy command.

```
COPY my_tablename
    (C1  
    ,C2   
    ,C3,...    
  )
    FROM 's3://<<YOUR-BUCKET>>/<<YOUR-FILE>>'
    credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret- access-key>';
```

> However, my VPC is set to allow my IP to connect. Does anyone know how to connect to a private cluster?

The command I have mentioned above should work fine from your machine which is white listed on `Redshift`.

Let me know if missed any question.

Comment: When I connect in the SQL client, I am using the credentials and url, however the connection always times out when it is set to private.  Also using the copy command and when creating the tables I have my credentials entered, yet it still doesn't want to connect.  I am unsure why

Comment: I think you may be missing enabling TCP in/out connection to port `5439`• Validate your inbound/outbound connection rules. We do exactly same as I have mentioned in answer to our production/as/dev Redshift environment and it really works.

Comment: Thank you, where do I enable that?  Is it in the VPC or the Redshift console?

Comment: Its part of VPC security rules, and then you attach particular VPC with your instance, here its Redshift your case.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to redshift using tools from your local machine?

Comment: @Fact Its not about `local machine` or `machine on cloud`, it works same way, i.e. if access is provided to `Redshift` using `security-rules` to any machine, it should be able to `connnect` to `Redshift cluster`.